# VSCode and TypeScript - refactoring/renaming without opening the affected files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code with a TypeScript application, is it possible to rename a variable/function without the affected files to be automatically open in the Editor area?

I'd like my refactorings to be automatically applied, the affected files immediately saved without being automatically open.

I know about the "`files.autoSave`" setting  and, by using "`afterDelay`", I'm indeed able to refactore without the affected files to be automatically open. But I don't want to work with this setting on! Mostly because of linting, the auto saving of files is really annoying.

Any way to perform an *immediate* refactoring?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like my refactorings to be automatically applied, the affected files immediately saved without being automatically open.

No its not possible out of the box.

## Why the default behaviour

You might do a refactor that you think is small but you end up refactoring 20 files.

## Changing it

You can create your own plugin with its own behaviour. That is what I would do if I was so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the new [**Rename preview** feature](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/c1284d9fb01f4e41711373e7189063c8ee17945f/release-notes/v1_42.md#rename-preview) of VSCode 1.42 (Q1 2020) would be an acceptable alternative (to opening the files)

> ### Rename preview
>
> VS Code now allows you to preview Rename changes.
> When renaming, you can confirm a new name via `kb(acceptRenameInputWithPreview)` and the Refactor Preview panel shows.
> It displays pending changes in a diff editor and allows you to uncheck/check individual changes.
> **Once the rename has been applied (or aborted), the diff editor and preview panel close, putting you back in the current editor.**

[image: Rename preview -- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/raw/vnext/release-notes/images/1_42/preview-rename-java.gif]

Answer (score 1):

VSCode 1.67 (Apr. 2022) will come with [Save automatically when refactoring #47573](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47573):

> Just like the feature "`Save automatically when Search & Replace`", after refactoring the code (by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> key or using context menu), the VS Code should save the file(s) automatically.

See [PR 146320](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/146320), available today with [VSCode insider release](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

> ### `files.refactoring.autoSave`
>
> Controls if files that were part of a refactoring are saved automatically.